Migrate from qemu to libvirt
I'm trying to run Bliss OS through QEMU by following this guide:
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -enable-kvm \
        -M q35 \
        -m 4096 -smp 4 -cpu host \
        -bios /usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF.fd \
        -drive file=Bliss11.qcow2,if=virtio \
        -usb \
        -device virtio-tablet \
        -device virtio-keyboard \
        -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci \
        -machine vmport=off \
        -device virtio-vga-gl -display sdl,gl=on \
        -audiodev pipewire,id=snd0 -device AC97,audiodev=snd0 \
        -net nic,model=virtio-net-pci -net user,hostfwd=tcp::4444-:5555

This setup works perfectly. However, when I try to run Bliss OS using virt-manager, I encounter issues. I've tried creating a new domain through the GUI and using the virt-install command, but both methods lead to problems:

Failed to initialize PW context
Failed to boot the OS and trapped into uefi shell

The final virt-install command that successfully create a new domain:
$ virt-install \
  --virt-type kvm \
  --name bliss-vm \
  --memory 4096 \
  --vcpus 4 \
  --cpu host \
  --os-variant generic \
  --import \
  --disk path=/home/reyuki/experiments/virtual-machine/blissOS/Bliss11.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio \
  --graphics sdl,gl=on \
  --controller usb,model=qemu-xhci \
  --input tablet,bus=virtio \
  --input keyboard,bus=virtio \
  --network network=default,model=virtio \
  --boot loader=/usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd,loader.readonly=yes,loader.type=pflash \
  --machine q35 \
  --connect qemu:///system \
  --check path_in_use=off

I’ve omitted the audio options to bypass the first error, but now I’m unable to boot the OS. I'm not sure why this is happening.
I also attempted to use the qemu-commandline option:
virt-install \
    --virt-type kvm \
    --name bliss-vm \
    --connect qemu:///system \
    --check path_in_use=off \
    --import \
    --disk path=/home/reyuki/experiments/virtual-machine/blissOS/Bliss11.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio \
    --os-variant generic \
    --memory 4096 \
    --vcpus 4 \
    --qemu-commandline '-M q35 -m 4096 -smp 4 -cpu host -bios /usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd -usb -device virtio-tablet -device virtio-keyboard -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci -machine vmport=off -device virtio-vga-gl -display sdl,gl=on -net nic,model=virtio-net-pci -net user,hostfwd=tcp::4444-:5555'

But this results in the following error: ERROR    internal error: QEMU unexpectedly closed the monitor (vm='bliss-vm'): 2024-08-28T03:12:37.710799Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device {"driver":"ich9-usb-ehci1","id":"usb","bus":"pci.0","addr":"0x5.0x7"}: Bus 'pci.0' not found
Could someone help me understand how to resolve these issues and get Bliss OS running smoothly with virt-manager?

Did you figure it out ?

unfortunately, not yet. I still using qemu directly for this purposes.

Could you add to the question the output of virsh dumpxml bliss-vm ?
